# How to get a single row per group where MAX(column) or first if none?

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following schema:

```
users:

id email
1  'user.one@test.com'
2  'user.two@test.com'

video_group:

id title
1  'Group 1'
2  'Group 2'

videos:

id group_id rank title
1  1        1    'Group 1 - Video 1'
2  1        2    'Group 1 - Video 2'
3  2        1    'Group 2 - Video 1'

user_video_play_times:

video_id user_id time last_update
2        1       12   01-02-2018
1        1       120  01-01-2018
```

I need to get the `time`, `user_id`, `video_id`, and `group_id` of the last video played by a user in specific groups, but if there's no records on `user_video_play_times` for a group, the video with the lowest rank should be returned. For example:

```
user_id group_id video_id time
1       1        2        12    -- user.one + group 1
1       2        3        0     -- user one + group 2
```

This is the query I have so far:

```
SELECT
   pt.user_id user_id,
   v.id       video_id,
   g.id       group_id,
   pt.time    time
FROM
   videos v
   INNER JOIN video_groups g ON g.id = v.group_id
   LEFT JOIN user_video_play_times pt ON 
      pt.video_id = v.id AND 
      pt.user_id = 1
   LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT 
         g.id AS g_id,
         MAX(pt.last_update) AS pt_last_update
      FROM
         user_video_play_times pt
         INNER JOIN videos v ON v.id = pt.video_id
         INNER JOIN video_groups g ON g.id = v.group_id
      WHERE
         pt.user_id = 1 AND
         g.id IN (1, 2)
      GROUP BY
         g.id
   ) lpt ON lpt.g_id = g.id AND lpt.pt_last_update = pt.last_update
WHERE
   g.id IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY
   g.id
```

It is sort of working, but...

1. Adding `v.title` to the column selection messes the results for some reason, making everything return only videos with rank 1. Any idea why?
2. Could this query be optimized, or is there another slicker way to achieve the same results?

Any help with this is really appreciated!

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=d67867c2124c40b5632b872aa8a07a8a)*

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for [_these techniques_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max#using_variables), which avoids showing dups.